# Magnolia CMS, iterate through components in different area

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I would like to create navigation in "header" area based on specific components in "content-body" area. All what I need is iterate through "content-body" area components and find that specific ones and pass them to the navigation template. I was wondering if someone can tell me how to iterate other area components from the different area controller.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```
[#assign yourOtherArea = cmsfn.contentByPath("/path/to/my/navigation/area")]
[@cms.area name="navigation" content=yourOtherArea/]
```

IMO it should be enough. `cms.area` directive doesn't care where the node it should render comes from.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Yea, it might work but I think it would be better to get information (components) that I need in the controller and just pass it to the template. I think it's better practice to make operation on content in controller and pass to the template only that what will be used. Any idea how to iterate through components from other area in blossom?

Comment: Hmm... lets say I have component "Anchor". I can add Anchor in the "body" area in any place. Anchor contains "Name" control, simple string. Now, what I would like to do, is iterate through all Anchors in "body" area, get theirs name and put it in the navigation.

Comment: @mickiewicz did you ever get a solution to this? Currently looking to do the same, I think.
I want to generate anchor links dynamically on the top of the page that takes the user to each section that contains an id. So would be wanting to loop through every magnolia component on the page and take any that has an id property and create an anchor.